# tabbarvisble is not working on a stacknavigator inside a bottomnavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How to hide tabbar on BarcodeScanner page?

I am currently setting false in inside the property in navigationOptions, but it is not working.

- Colect

  - BarcodeScanner
- Visualization

this is my current code

```
const Routes = createAppContainer(
  createBottomTabNavigator({
    GroupColect: {
      screen: createStackNavigator({
        PageColect: {
          screen: Colect,
          navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
          },
        },
        PageBarcodeScanner: {
          screen: BarcodeScanner,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: false,
          },
        },
      }),
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Coleta',
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="format-list-bulleted" size={20} color={tintColor} />,
      },
    },
    Visualization,
  }, {
    tabBarOptions: {
      keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
      activeTintColor: '#FFF',
      inactiveTintColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67)',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#8ac523',
      },
    },
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `tabBarVisible: false` in `PageBarcodeScanner`, it applies to the wrapping navigator. In your example, the wrapping navigator is a stack, not a tab bar, so it has no effect.

Obviously you could apply the property to one of the stack of the tab bar (for instance GroupColect), but that would hide the bar for all the screens in the stack, which is not what you want.

What you want is hide the tab bar on the second screen on the stack. Actually the official docs covers [this exact use case](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-tab-navigator-contains-a-stack-and-you-want-to-hide-the-tab-bar-on-specific-screens).

Let's refactor your code a little bit:

```js
const GroupColectStack = createStackNavigator({
  PageColect: {
    screen: Colect,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
  PageBarcodeScanner: {
    screen: BarcodeScanner,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarVisible: false,
    },
  },
});

const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  GroupColect: {
    screen: GroupColectStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Coleta',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="format-list-bulleted" size={20} color={tintColor} />,
    },
  },
  Visualization,
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
    activeTintColor: '#FFF',
    inactiveTintColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.67)',
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#8ac523',
    },
  },
});

const Routes = createAppContainer(BottomTabs);
```

I haven't changed anything, just separated the different navigators.

Now all you have to do is add this part:

```js
GroupColectStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let tabBarVisible = true;
  if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
    tabBarVisible = false;
  }

  return {
    tabBarVisible,
  };
};
```

This will keep the tab bar on the first screen but hide it on the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one `StackNavigator` for all stacks and set `TabNavigator` as the default path. Please reset the path.

- StackNavigator

  - TabNavigator

    - PageColect
    - PageBarcodeScanner

You can hide the header in many ways.

You can use `navigationOptions`
**header**
React Element or a function that given `HeaderProps` returns a React Element, to display as a header. Setting to `null` hides header.

```js
        PageBarcodeScanner: {
          screen: BarcodeScanner,
          navigationOptions: () => ({
             header: null,
             tabBarVisible: false,

          }),
```

**static navigationOptions**

```js
class BarcodeScanner extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    tabBarVisible: false,
  };
```

or `Stacknavigation Options`

`headerMode` - Specifies how the header should be rendered:

- `none` - No header will be rendered.

```js
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Your Stack Navigation
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headermode: 'none'
  }
);
```

Comment: This works only if you need a header that does nothing. What if he needs to navigate to a nested screen? The main stack wont detect it, as the only screen it has is the tabNavigator.

Comment: If you place a tab inside a stack navigator, you can move it.

Comment: What do you mean with "move it"?

Comment: This refers to the movement between screens.

Comment: I don't think a nested screen would be able to work without doing some tricks with setParams. How would it be if you have a NewsScreen and a NewsDetailScreen with a main header?